# asp.net dnxcore50 load assembly by file path

Tags: c#, reflection, dnx, .net-core

How do you load an assembly in asp.net under dnxcore50 (DNX Core 5.0)?

I have a Lib/FooLibrary.dll path in the directory where my asp.net 5 app lives, but i cannot seem to find any way of loading the assembly via reflection

My ultimate goal is to use reflection to load the assembly and get some MethodInfos in order to do some light-weight code generation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are after **IAssemblyLoadContextAccessor** and **IAssemblyLoaderContainer**.

Example of usage can be found at asp.net home repo at github [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Entropy/tree/dev/samples/Runtime.CustomLoader).

Comment: That is a good starting point, but now i am struggling with getting the path to the app... I am getting the following error:
Absolute path information is required.
Parameter name: assemblyPath

To debug, I am running the app on IISExpress, but cant seem to figure out how to get to the DLL

Comment: Example link is broken